# How to find and replace part of formula in all cells in excel

Tags: excel, replace, formula

Is the a way to use find and replace in excel formulas. Like I have a formula in some cells like this:

```
GETPIVOTDATA("Sales", $A$4, "Region", "South")
```

I want to replace `Sales` to `New_Sales`

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Press `Ctrl` and `H`to open the replace option, click "advanced" and tick the relevant options like "look in formulas". Then choose to replace `"Sales"` with `"New_Sales"`, including the quotes to ensure you don't go round in circles

Answer (score 8):

If it is really all the formulas in the sheet it will be easy to use the normal find and replace. If not, use the below approach,

- Press Ctrl + ` (back quote) in the sheet. This will make all the formulas visible
- Now as you see all the formulas, select the range that you want to replace
- `Ctrl + H` and follow the normal find and replace process

This approach is to make sure that you modify the formulas that you need and not all others

Comment: TIL that `Ctrl-\`` reveals formulas on Excel for Mac, as Excel for Mac's "Find/Replace" doesn't have any advanced options.  Awesome answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use find and replace (Ctrl + Shift + H or on the Home Ribbon, click on the Find & Select button under editing).

Once the form pops open, select Look In "Formulas" and then type in the Find what and Replace with values. e.g. Sales and New_Sales.

You can choose to replace just the one found or replace all. Ifo you make a mistake you can always undo.